# EditText автоотключение клавиатуры при достижении максимальной длины

Tags: android

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Имя товарища"
        android:maxLength="10" />
```

Подскажите, как сделать отключение клавиатуры при достижении максимальной длины?

Comment: Не понял, а как применить для конкретного EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключите в `TextWatcher`, а именно в методе `onTextChanged()`:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Можно ли это сделать для всех EditText активности?

Comment: Да, конечно. Используйте общий класс `TextWatcher`